# MYSQL COUNT FUNCTION Across Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, count

I have a user_id key that shows up in **Table A**, **Table B**, **Table C**.

Table A

```
User_id value
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

Table B

```
User_id value
1       A
1       B
1       C
```

Table C

```
User_id value
1       A
1       B
0       C
```

tA is unique on **User_id**. I am trying to get the number of occurrences in Table B and Table C with that user_id in one query.

I tried:

```
SELECT tA.user_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM tB as countB GROUP BY tA.user_id),(SELECT count(*) FROM tC as countC GROUP BY tA.user_id) FROM tA where tA.user_id='1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
select ta.user_id,
  (select count(*) from tb where ta.user_id = tb.user_id) CountB,
  (select count(*) from tc where ta.user_id = tc.user_id) CountC
from ta
where ta.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using count(distinct)?

```
SELECT tA.user_id, count(distinct tB.id), count(distinct tC.id) FROM tA, tB, tC 
WHERE tA.user_id=tB.user_id AND tA.user_id=tC.user_id AND tA.user_id='1';
```

Edit: This is assuming you have a unique field on tB and tC.